# EF Core 3.0 - Unable to query abstract entities (ie., root entities in a hierarchy)

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

My application has a model like the one below:

```
public abstract class Vehicle { .... }
public class Car : Vehicle { .... }
public class Boat : Vehicle { .... }
...
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   ...
   modelBuilder.Entity<Vehicle>()
      .HasDiscriminator<int>("Type")
         .HasValue<Car>(1)     
         .HasValue<Boat>(2)
   ...
   public DbSet<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Boat> Boats { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

The following query returned all CARS and BOATS on EF Core 2.*

```
from t in context.Vehicles select t
```

But the same query returns always empty on EF Core 3.0.

The SQL Profiler shows that EF Core 3.0 is appending the following to the query WHERE clause

```
SELECT * FROM VEHICLE WHERE CAST(0 AS bit) = CAST(1 AS bit)
```

Is this by design? If so, a lot of code on my application is now broken.

Any suggestion on how I can circunvent this behavior?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with the provided information (appended is `WHERE [v].[Type] IN (2, 1)` as expected). There must be something else not shown here.

Comment: In fact, the query has a WHERE clause, more like "from t in context.Vehicles where t.model.Equals('model-x')  .... select t", but for the sake of simplicity I did not include the WHERE clause.

Comment: Please enhance your question with enough information to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Something in your `Where` clause is causing EF Core 3 to think it always evaluates to `false`. It might be explicit `Where` clause or global query filter. Try reproducing with just the code from the post, and if you can't, then add other parts from the original until it reproduces.

Comment: I found the problem. Maybe it is a bug on EF 3.0. The problem is the 'Equals()' function. If I change from `t.model.Equals('model-x')` to `t.model == 'model-x'` it works. For some reason the Equals() is buggy on EF 3.0 (this same query was working on EF 2.*)